# Group rows and sum the last column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My original data looks like this:

[image]

I want my data to be transformed into:

[image]

Is there any way that we can do this without using pivot/subtotals. The reason why I am against pivot/subtotals is because i want to merge this data with some other data and do some calculations. VBA holds good too.

Any ideas please? I do not want the entire solution here, just suggest me some idea to proceed. I did a bit of research and all those were just the pointers to Pivot/Subtotals.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett The above question which i have asked can simply be achieved by using Subtotal's in excel. I am not asking for a complete solution instead i am asking for the ideas. Whether the above problem can be achieved or not by not using the in-built standard functions. I did some research and all the solutions i found was related to the Pivot tables and Subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Please share your code/research.

**For the "Total Effort" try:**

```
=SUM(IF(B$2:B$9=G2;D$2:D$9))
```

And hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when editing the cell value. Then drag it down.

Where "G2" is the "Name" value. "B2:B9" is the "Name" column and "D2:D9" is the "Total Effort" column.

**Other columns:**

To get the other columns you need to get the unique values. Try this for the ID column (assuming you want the unique IDs in Column F):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9;MATCH(0;INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1;$A$2:$A$9);0;0);0))
```

And hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when editing the cell value. Then drag it down until you get #N/A values.

Where "A2:A9" is the "ID" column. "F1:F1" is the new column with the unique "ID".

Comment: A simple [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) may be a better suggestion than an *array formula* for the totals.

Comment: Sure you are right - both solutions will give the same result. I personally don't like however the ***IF functions - prefer array functions.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time for sundy data munging, you can connect to the workbook using ADO and run a SQL groupby statement on the sheet.

If you don't want to use VBA then you can do the same thing with microsoft query, though its a bit clunky using Data> from other sources > From microsoft query (data source = excel file).

For an easier query builder you could just import your table into Access and run a groupby query there, then copy paste it back.